# How can I limit the scope of selenium "find_elements_by_xpath" for star-counting in each row?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I tried to count the stars(ratings) of each rating column in this url 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies' by using selenium to automate the whole process.

For the star-counting part, there are 5 rows of star ratings.
I try to use for loop to limit the scope of each star_count stored in the list and therefore getting the star rating given by each user. However, this approach  doesn't seem to work as what stored in the list turned out to be: 
1. 22
2. 22 
3. 22 
4. 22
5. 22

Which implies that my for loop doesn't work in limiting the counting scope. May I know are there other ways to limit the counting scope to achieve my aim?

Thanks in advance.

```
##These are basic setups
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

'''Create new instance of Chrome in Incognito mode'''
##Adding the incognito argument to our webdriver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
##create a new instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/w97802/chromedriver')

'''Scrape Basic Info'''
from parsel import Selector
url = 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies'
browser.get(url)
selector = Selector(text=browser.page_source)

####################################################################
##This is the star-count code
'''Count stars simple'''
star_count_list = []

ratingcolumn = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"qr0ren-7 euifNX")]')
for row in ratingcolumn:
    star_count = 0
    stars = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="qr0ren-7 euifNX"]/span/span/span[contains(@style,"width:100%")]')
    for targets in stars:
        star_count += 1
    star_count_list.append(star_count)

'''Print Stars Result''' 
for i,e in enumerate(star_count_list, start=1):
        print ('\n \n \n ' + str(i) + '. \n', e)
```

Comment: to limit you should use `row.find_...` instead of `browser.find_...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things, use `row` to locate the elements instead of `browser` and add `.` to the `xpath` to specify current context

```
stars = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span/span/span[contains(@style,"width:100%")]')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this, and turned out the result is "0" stars for every rating column.

Comment: And I tried leaving out ".", the result is again "22" for each rating column. May I know why?

Comment: @JoeyWong `row` is already the `<div>` with class `"qr0ren-7 euifNX", you need to start the search from the child element (updated the answer). `xpath` start the search from the root. `.` tells it the root is the `WebElement` you are using.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your help! Wish you an awesome year ahead!

Answer (score 0):

To search only in one row you have to use `row` instead of `browser`

```
stars = row.find_elements_by_xpath(...)
```

---

**EDIT:** I forgot about `.` which you have to use to create `xpath` relative to `row` instead of using absolute `xpath`

```
ratingcolumn = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"qr0ren-7 euifNX")]')

for row in ratingcolumn:
    stars = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@style,"width:100%")]')

    star_count_list.append(len(stars))
```

**BTW:** you can also uses `//` to skip some tags.

And you can `len(starts)` instead of `for`-loop to count elements in list `stars`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this, and turned out the result is "22" stars for every rating column. May I know why?

Comment: I fogot about `.` in xpath to use xpath relative to row, not absolut xpath.

Comment: I added code with `.`. I also used `len()` to count stars